# How to get php var value that create after load page?

Tags: javascript, php

First load this page `test1.php` then click `CREATE VAR` (var `$_SESSION["test_var"]` will create) then click `ALERT VAR`, i want to know how can i get alert var result by not to load page again

test1.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$sessionid = session_id();
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="alert_fn()">ALERT VAR</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<script>
function alert_fn(){
    alert("<?PHP echo $_SESSION["test_var"]; ?>");
}
</script>

<div onclick="create_var_fn()">CREATE VAR</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="xx_span"></div>    


<form id="fid" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="xx" id="xx">
</form>

<script>
function create_var_fn(){
    $.ajax
    (
        {
            url: 'test2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#fid').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#xx_span').show();
                $('#xx_span').html(data);
            }
        }
    )
}
</script>
```

test2.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$_SESSION["test_var"] = "test";
echo $_SESSION["test_var"];
?>
```

Comment: You'll have to turn `alert_fn` into a function that makes a request to another one of your endpoints, and have said endpoint return the session value in question.

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear. Can you specify what problem you are facing right now? Something which is not working?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. That means it runs *before the page goes to the browser*. You can't interact with it this way. Use AJAX.